# How can the output of an existing PowerShell script be displayed?

Tags: powershell

How can the output of an existing PowerShell script be displayed?

`G:\WriteOutput.ps1` contains a variable `$Output`

My example command is shown below.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> G:\WriteOutput.ps1 | Write $Output

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.3#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) the script - this way any variables created by the script will persist in the calling scope:

```
PS ~> . G:\WriteOutput.ps1
PS ~> $Output # this variable still exists after the script finishes now
```

To avoid polluting the global scope, do so inside another script block and then output the value of the `$Output` variable from there:

```
PS ~> & { $null = . G:\WriteOutput.ps1; $Output }
```